# Formula for multivariate Joe copula

Tags: multivariate-analysis, copula

According to p. 150-151 of Cherubini et al. ["Copula Methods in Finance"](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Copula+Methods+in+Finance-p-9780470863442) (2004), here are some $n$-variate Archimedean copulas:

**Clayton copula**
The generator is $\phi(u) = u^{-\alpha}-1$ and the Clayton copula is
$$
C(u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n)=\left( u_1^{-\alpha}+ \ldots + u_n^{-\alpha} - n+1\right)^{-1/\alpha}, \qquad 
\alpha > 0.
$$

**Gumbel copula**
The generator is $\phi(u)=(-\ln(u))^\alpha$ and the Gumbel copula is
$$
C(u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n)=\exp \bigg ( -\Big[\big(-\ln(u_1) \big )^\alpha + \ldots + \big(-\ln(u_n) \big )^\alpha \Big]^{1/\alpha}\bigg ), \qquad 
\alpha > 1.
$$

**Frank copula**
The generator is $\phi(u) = \ln \Big ( \frac{\exp(-\alpha u)-1}{\exp(-\alpha )-1} \Big )$ and the Frank copula is
$$
C(u_1, u_2, \ldots, u_n)=-\frac{1}{\alpha} \ln \bigg [ 1 + \frac{(e^{-\alpha u_1}-1) \cdot \ldots \cdot (e^{-\alpha u_n}-1)}{(e^{-\alpha}-1)^{n-1}}  \bigg ], \qquad 
\alpha > 0.
$$

**Question:** Is there an equivalent expression for an $n$-variate Joe copula (if such copula exists in the first place)?

Comment: @dmi3kno, this is the document I cite in my answer.

Comment: Did not mean to steal the drum. Hope you don't consider my comment to be a threat to your excellent answer. Here's my upvote!

Comment: @dmi3kno, no I did not think about it as a threat. I was just quite surprised to discover that you have provided the exact same information as in the answer, though without giving a full reference. (It also took me a while to discover that.) I do not quite get why one would do that. But there is zero harm done :) And thanks for the upvote :)

Answer (score 1):

**My approach:**

According to Theorem 4.10 and Definition 4.14 of Cherubini et al. (2004) (p. 149-150) as cited above, $n$-variate Archimedean copulas can be generated in a simple way. Let $\varphi$ be a strict generator, with $\varphi^{-1}$ completely monotonic on $[0,\infty]$. Then an $n$-variate Archimedean copula is the function
$$
C(u_1, \dots, u_n) = \varphi^{-1}[ (\varphi(u_1) + \dots + \varphi(u_n)].
$$
Let us try to apply this to the Joe copula. According to Table 1 on p. 6 in Krouthen ["Extreme joint dependencies with copulas A new approach for the structure of C-Vines"](https://uu.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:827739/FULLTEXT01.pdf) (2015), the generator of the Joe copula is
$$
\varphi(u) = -\ln \Big( 1−(1−u)^\alpha \Big), \qquad \alpha\geq 1.
$$
After some algebra I obtain the inverse generator to be
$$
\varphi^{-1}(x) = 1-[1-\exp(-x)]^{1/\alpha}.
$$
Then the $n$-variate Joe copula then should be
$$
C(u_1, \ldots, u_n) = 1 - \bigg( 1 - \exp\big[(\ln\{1-(1−u_1)^\alpha\}+\ldots+ (\ln\{1-(1−u_n)^\alpha\}\big] \bigg)^{1/\alpha}
$$
which after some algebra simplifies to
$$
C(u_1, \ldots, u_n) = 1 - \bigg( 1 - \big[1-(1−u_1)^\alpha\big] \cdot\ldots\cdot \big[1-(1−u_n)^\alpha\big] \bigg)^{1/\alpha}.
$$
This only holds for the values of $\alpha$ that make the inverse of the generator, $\varphi^{-1}(x) = 1-[1-\exp(-x)]^{1/\alpha}$, monotonic on $[0,\infty]$. The latter set of values seems to be $\alpha\in[0,\infty)$. Combined with the requirement $\alpha\geq 1$ above, we have $\alpha\in[1,\infty)$.

**Does that look OK?**

---

**Update:** the following anecdotal evidence suggests it is OK. I have compared 3-variate and 4-variate Joe copulas from the `copula` package in R with an implementation of what I have derived above. For a concrete parameter value and a couple of concrete data points, I get matching values of the copula (cumulative density).

```r
library(copula)

u=seq(from=0.1,to=0.9,by=0.1) # hypothetical values of a probability integral transform of a 9-variate observation
alpha=2 # the copula parameter

# 3- and 4-dimensional Joe copulas from the [`copula`][2] package
joe.cop=joeCopula(param=alpha, dim=3); print(pCopula(u[1:3], joe.cop))
joe.cop=joeCopula(param=alpha, dim=4); print(pCopula(u[1:4], joe.cop))

# 3- and 4-dimensional Joe copulas based on the derivation in this post
pcop3=1-(1-(1-(1-u[1])^alpha)*(1-(1-u[2])^alpha)*(1-(1-u[3])^alpha)                   )^(1/alpha); print(pcop3)
pcop4=1-(1-(1-(1-u[1])^alpha)*(1-(1-u[2])^alpha)*(1-(1-u[3])^alpha)*(1-(1-u[4])^alpha))^(1/alpha); print(pcop4)
```